# How to pass a variable from Javascript to PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap

I've checked dozens of similar topics already answered and I simply can't get around the issue I have.
I am using a bootstrap date time picker (https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker) and my goal is to pass the displayed value from a page that holds the calendar (calendar.php) to a PHP file (data.php) whenever the date is changed.

Below I added the code. Since I have some files locally stored, I added some info from Chrome's dev tools.

The date picker is working fine and I can get the value with Javascript.
The issue is that nothing is passed to PHP.
Checked the syntax..everything seems fine for me at this point. 
I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Any advice would be more than welcomed !

calendar.php :

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
            <div  class='input-group date'  id='datetimepicker1' >
            <input type='text' id='date' name='date' class="form-control" >
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
           </div>
         </div>
 <script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function() {
  $(function () {
   // Formatting how date is displayed
    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
    calendarWeeks: true,
    format: "YYYY MM DD"
        });
//Displaying the current date in the text box when the page is accessed
$('#datetimepicker1').data("DateTimePicker").date(new Date());

// Sending the date to PHP when the user is changing it
//dp.change is an event fired when date is changed
$('#datetimepicker1').on("dp.change",function(){
var day  = $('#date').val();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:  "data.php",
     data: { day : day } })
    .done(function() { alert(day); })
    .fail(function() { alert("error"); })

});
})

})
</script>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I execute the code, it alerts me with the day ( it goes to .done(function() { alert(day); }) ) and in my current understanding, the post was a success or at least that's how I interpret it. 
This is from Chrome's dev tool.
I am trying to show that the value is retrieved. No other errors appear.

```
// Sending the date to PHP when the user is changing it
 $('#datetimepicker1').on("dp.change",function(){
var day  = $('#date').val(); // Date gets retrieved : day = "2016 08 03"
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:  "data.php",
data: { day : day } }) // Date gets retrived: day = "2016 08 03"
    .done(function() { alert(day); }) // I get a pop-up with the date
    .fail(function() { alert("error"); })

});
})

})
```

The file with Javascript code and the file with PHP code are in the same folder.

PHP (data.php) code is below :

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['day']))
{
$day = $_POST['day'];

echo $day;
}

?>
```

I simply can't figure what am I doing wrong or missing in the code above.

Edit :

I think I didn't focused well on the issue I am having and I am sorry for that. All your suggestions ( thanks a lot for them) are about the .done(function).

My issue is that my php file (data.php) is empty. The date isn't passed by the Ajax and I don't know why. The post doesn't happen.
I tried all the suggestions u guys mentioned, thinking that they may be the answer but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP is outputting the value. The web server is sending the value to the browser. The browser is giving that value to JavaScript. jQuery is processes that value. Then you ignore it.

It is passed as the first argument to the function you pass to `done`, use it.

```
.done(function(data_in_response) { alert(data_in_response); })
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer Quentin. Unfortunately and I edited the post also, my issue is with my data.php file ; the file doesn't receive the data sent from calendar.php. and I really can't figure what am I missing. 

P.S : I also tried your solution thinking that it may be the answer I was looking for but no luck.

Comment: "the file doesn't receive the data sent from calendar.php" — What makes you think that? All it does is echo the data back to the JS and your JS ignores it.

Comment: "I also tried your solution" — What happened when you tried?

Comment: What have you done to figure out what is happening? Are you using the developer tools built into your browser to check the Console for errors and the Network tab to see what data is being sent to the server and what the server is responding with?

Comment: The Network tab really helped and I saw exactly what "data_in_response" is about and how data.php sends the data. Thanks for the pointers.
I managed to achieve what I was hoping to do.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the same variable inside the ajax response function to print on response, i.e.,

```
.done(function(data){
  alert(data);
})
```